# Extract decimal Number from string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am trying to extract numbers from my string using the following code:

```
var mat = Regex.Match(stringValue, @"\d+").Value;
```

But when `stringValue` contains a decimal like "($23.01)", It only extracts 23 instead of 23.01. How can I get the `decimal` value 23.01?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to approach the problem this way. A decimal number has the following features:

- start with one or more digits (`\d+`)
- after that, there can be one or 0 dots (`\.?`)
- if a dot is present, one or more digits should also follow (`\d+`)

Since the last two features are kind of related, we can put it in a group and add a `?` quantifier: `(\.\d+)?`.

So now we have the whole regex: `\d+(\.\d+)?`

If you want to match decimal numbers like `.01` (without the 0 at the front), you can just use `|` to mean "or" and add another case `(\.\d+)`. Basically: `(\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+)`

Comment: `10.` or `.01` aren't valid decimal numbers?

Comment: @xunatai No I don't consider them as decimal numbers

Comment: @xunatai `10.` will just match `10` anyway. And you just need to do `\d*` instead of `\d+` at the start to match `.01`

Comment: @xunatai Oops! That was my quick thinking. `(\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+)` should work.

Comment: @Sweeper will it work if string contains  "($23)" and no decimal value?

Comment: @HumaAli it will. Why not try it for yourself?

Comment: @Sweeper Just did. It works :)

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried [this Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h5ewTz):

```
string inputStr =  "($23.01)";      
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(inputStr, @"\d+.+\d").Value);
```

Or else you can try this LinqSolution:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(inputStr.Where(x=> x=='.'||Char.IsDigit(x))));
```

Comment: when string contains "($23)", This will fail

Comment: @HumaAli: `Regex` will fail with that input you can try the Linq solution then

Comment: just add a question mark at the end: \d+.+\d?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

var mat= Regex.Split(stringValue, @"[^0-9.]+")
    .Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != "");